How to upload array of objects (multiple image files) in Node.js
I have an issue in my app. Here is the object, we have motherPhoto, fatherPhoto,spousePhoto and siblingsPhoto to be uploaded..
{
  "mothername": "kerin",
  "motherPhoto": "C:/fakepath/mother.jpg",
  "fathername": "kako",
  "fatherPhoto": "C:/fakepath/father.jpg",
  "spousename": "kiki",
  "spousePhoto": "C:/fakepath/wife.jpg",
  "siblingDetails": [
    {
      "siblingsName": "",
      "siblingsDob": "",
      "siblingsEmail": "",
      "siblingsPhone": "",
      "siblingsPhoto": "C:/fakepath/LW.jpg"
    },
    {
      "siblingsName": "",
      "siblingsDob": "",
      "siblingsEmail": "",
      "siblingsPhone": "",
      "siblingsPhoto": "C:/fakepath/LW1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "siblingsName": "",
      "siblingsDob": "",
      "siblingsEmail": "",
      "siblingsPhone": "",
      "siblingsPhoto": "C:/fakepath/LW2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "siblingsName": "",
      "siblingsDob": "",
      "siblingsEmail": "",
      "siblingsPhone": "",
      "siblingsPhoto": "C:/fakepath/LW4.jpg"
    }
  ]
}

I'm able to get, motherPhoto, fatherPhoto,spousePhoto but siblingsPhoto is {} empty object in react:
const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    
        event.preventDefault()
        setValidated(true)
        

        let error = hasError(formData)
        if (isEmpty(error)) {
            
            let data = new FormData()
            Object.keys(formData).forEach((key) => {
                if (key === 'siblingsDetails') {
                    if (formData.isSiblings === 'No') {
                        data.append('siblingsDetails', JSON.stringify([]))
                    } else {
                        console.log(formData[key], 'formData[key]')
                        data.append(key, JSON.stringify(formData[key]))
                    }
                } else {
                    data.append(key, formData[key])
                }
            })
            await applyCareer(data)
        } else {
            
            const a = Object.keys(error)
            event.target.querySelector('#' + a[0]).focus()
            setErrors(error)
        }
    }
    const applyCareer = async (data: any) => {
        try {
            await axios.post(
                `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}job-applications/add/personalInfo`,
                data,
                {
                    headers: {
                        applicant: 'hello',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

in nodejs
import multer from "multer";

const router = express.Router();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.fieldname === 'motherPhoto') {
        cb(null, 'uploads/careers/personalInfo/motherPhoto/');

      }else if (file.fieldname === 'fatherPhoto') {
        cb(null, 'uploads/careers/personalInfo/fatherPhoto/');

      }else if (file.fieldname === 'spousePhoto') {
       cb(null, 'uploads/careers/personalInfo/spousePhoto/');

     }else  if (file.fieldname === 'siblingsPhoto') {
        cb(null, 'uploads/careers/personalInfo/siblingsPhoto/');

      } 
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {

 
      const userId = req.headers.applicant;
      let filename = '';
    
      if (file.fieldname === 'fatherPhoto') {
        filename = `${userId}_Father_${Date.now()}.${file.mimetype.split('/')[1]}`;
      } else
      if (file.fieldname === 'motherPhoto') {
        filename = `${userId}_mother_${Date.now()}.${file.mimetype.split('/')[1]}`;
      } else
      if (file.fieldname === 'spousePhoto') {
        filename = `${userId}_spouse_${Date.now()}.${file.mimetype.split('/')[1]}`;
      }else
    
      if (file.fieldname === 'siblingsPhoto') {
        filename = `${userId}_sibling_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
      } 
  
      cb(null, filename);
    },
  });
  
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

  router.post("/add/personalInfo", upload.fields([
    { name: 'passportImage', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'fatherPhoto', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'motherPhoto', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'spousePhoto', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'siblingsPhoto', maxCount: 10 } // Allow up to 10 sibling photos
  ]),async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        console.log(req.files,'files')
      
      
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
        
    }
  })

The siblingsPhoto array is not being populated correctly on the server side. In the React code, siblingsPhoto is an empty object when I check the req.files on the server.
How can I correctly handle and upload multiple siblingsPhoto files along with other individual photo fields in this setup?

i think, siblings data is not being sent correctly from the client-side. just to resolve the problem you should start by appending data of each sibbling separately; later on you can improve your data structure. change the above if (key === 'siblingsDetails') block like this:
if (key === 'siblingsDetails') {
       // Handle(append) multiple sibling object separatly here
       formData[key]?.forEach((sibling, index) => {
           data.append(`siblingsDetails[${index}][siblingsName]`, sibling.siblingsName);
           data.append(`siblingsDetails[${index}][siblingsDob]`, sibling.siblingsDob);
           data.append(`siblingsDetails[${index}][siblingsEmail]`, sibling.siblingsEmail);
           data.append(`siblingsDetails[${index}][siblingsPhone]`, sibling.siblingsPhone);
           data.append(`siblingsPhoto[${index}]`, sibling.siblingsPhotoFile);
       });
}

